# Apache will not stop/start gracefully

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, selinux, centos6.4

CentOs 6 64bit running apache  2.2.15-29.el6.centos.
When I try to stop/start or restart httpd I get an error that says it has failed.  A tail of the error log is below.  I also noticed that a httpd.pid file is not created even though it is configured in the main conf file.

If I set selinux to permissive, it works just fine.  I do not want to run it with selinux disabled.  If I delete the SSL_Mutex file it will start.

HTTPD was running fine until I tried to add the ssl configuration.  I copied over the ssl.conf file from a working server into the conf.d folder.  I also copied a sslcert folder into the conf folder.  It contains the certs, key, csr and password file.  I think the problem has to do with the selinux context for the sslcert folder that was copied but I am not certain and not sure how to fix it.

Below is the security context for the sslcert folder after executing `restorecon -R sslcert`
`ls -Z`

```
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 httpd.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 magic
**drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 sslcert**
```

`tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`

```
[Thu Oct 17 13:33:19 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 17 13:33:20 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Oct 17 13:33:20 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Oct 17 13:33:20 2013] [warn] pid file /etc/httpd/logs/ssl.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Oct 17 13:33:20 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 17 21:04:48 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 17 21:06:42 2013] [notice] **SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0**
[Thu Oct 17 21:06:42 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 17 21:06:42 2013] [error] (17)File exists: Cannot create SSLMutex with file `/etc/httpd/logs/ssl_mutex'
```

I also saw mention of possible issues with semaphores.  Below is the output of the current semaphores and apache is currently not running.

`ipcs -s`

```
------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
0x00000000 0          root       600        1
0x00000000 65537      root       600        1
```

Finally selinux reports the following error.

```
`sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`  
0% donetype=AVC msg=audit(1382034755.118:420400): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=3393 comm="httpd" name="ssl_mutex" dev=dm-0 ino=9513484 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 tclass=file

**** Invalid AVC allowed in current policy ***

100% doneERROR: failed to read complete file, 1044649 bytes read out of total 1043317 bytes (/var/log/audit/audit.log)
found 1 alerts in /var/log/audit/audit.log
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from remove_name access on the directory ssl_mutex.
```

Comment: -1 purely for lack of formatting effort. Could you please edit your question and use some of the formatting options available here to make it easier to read?

Comment: I was not aware of all the formatting features.  I hope it is up to snuff.  I would have happily done it at your request.  Downgrading the question wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar problem appiered before:

http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-selinux-list/2004-December/msg00067.html

Check for  ssl mutex config to be same as in default ssl.conf.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that led me down the correct path.  I changed the SSLMutex directive to the line below.  This allows httpd to stop and start properly using apachectl.  I am still having some issues using the init.d script but I will open another question for that.  `SSLMutex default`

Comment: For me this was an artifact of migrating from default httpd config on  CentOS 5 to CentOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

> If I set selinux to permissive, it works just fine. I do not want to run it with selinux
>   disabled. If I delete the SSL_Mutex file it will start.

add "rm -fv /path/to/apache/ssl_mutex_file" to your httpd init script?

> [Thu Oct 17 21:06:42 2013] [error] (17)File exists: Cannot create SSLMutex with file
>   `/etc/httpd/logs/ssl_mutex'

kinda hackish, but should work.  i usually disable selinux on non-shared servers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I am hoping to fix it without hacking.  This is a production server that I am trying to keep as secure as possible.  I would prefer to find the root cause of the problem and fix it.